# For Loop not looping despite logging a count for the array being looped

Tags: ios, loops, for-loop

Here is the log:

```
2016-02-05 08:17:39.037 ASAP[70510:7996026] sortTasksIntoDaySeperatedArrays | SORTED_TASKS:(
        {
        "TASK_DURRATION" = 1;
        "TASK_NAME" = Now;
        "TASK_START_TIME" = 1454678259;
    },
        {
        "DAY_OF_WEEK" = Sunday;
        "TASK_DURRATION" = 600;
        "TASK_NAME" = "Sunday Breakfast 9AM";
        "TASK_START_TIME" = 1454853634;
    }
)
2016-02-05 08:17:39.065 ASAP[70510:7996026] DAYS_COUNT:7
2016-02-05 08:17:39.065 ASAP[70510:7996026] FINAL_END_GAME_ARRAY:(
)
```

**FUNCTION**

```
-(void)sortTasksIntoDaySeperatedArrays{

    NSMutableArray *FinalSortedDaysArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *nextSevenDaysArray=[self nextSevenDays];
    NSLog(@"NEXT_SEVEN:%@",nextSevenDaysArray);
    NSMutableArray *sortedTasks=[self getAndSortAllTasks];
    NSLog(@"sortTasksIntoDaySeperatedArrays | SORTED_TASKS:%@",sortedTasks);
    NSLog(@"DAYS_COUNT:%lu",(unsigned long)nextSevenDaysArray.count);

    int q;
    for(q = 0;q ==7;q = q + 1){
        NSLog(@"LOOP");


    }


    NSLog(@"FINAL_END_GAME_ARRAY:%@",FinalSortedDaysArray);

}
```

Comment: Can you expand in your question what issue you're seeing.

Comment: see the log i added....it logs that there is a 7 count to the array, but when it gets to the loop it never logs the word LOOP at all.

Comment: This is insanity....even this will not log out ANYTHING:   
-(void)theLoop{
    int q;
    for(q = 0;q ==7;q = q + 1){
        NSLog(@"LOOOP");
    }
}

Comment: Try changing `q = q + 1` to `q++`. You can also move the `int q` into the `for loop` as well, unless you need the final value.

Comment: No change....nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(q = 0;q ==7;q = q + 1)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

this will go through the loop while the test condition is true - that is, while q = 7, which will never happen as you have just set it to 0

If you want to go through **until** q = 7, you do it like this

```
for(q = 0;q < 7; q++)
{
    // do stuff
}
```